# Current Identity does not have access to Temporary ASP.NET Files n VSTS

Tags: asp.net, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to build an old ASP.NET 3.5 project with Visual Studio Team Services. When it comes to the build solution, I am getting this error:

> ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPRUNTIME: The current identity
>   (TASKAGENT5-0010\buildguest) does not have write access to
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files'.

I am using a Hosted Agent. Since that is not my machine, I wonder how to fix it.
Any idea?

Comment: I don't have way to test, but is this any use to you? http://serverfault.com/questions/350550/is-it-possible-to-configure-the-location-of-temporary-asp-net-files-folder-in

Comment: Is your project able to run locally? Which permission does identity TASKAGENT5-0010\buildguest have? Do you use old XAML build or the new build system? How's your build definition like?

Comment: I've tried creating a asp.net 3.5 project in VS2015 and checking it to VSTS, creating a new build definition with default VS template (new build system), the build ran successfully. You may provide your steps to reproduce this issue and check this case to see whether it is helpful: https://forums.asp.net/t/948328.aspx

Comment: If possible, please share your project.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT sorry for my late answer. I have a regular Class Library and a Website (not web application) project. I usethe new build system. There is nothing really special about the build steps. Two Copy steps to copy the dependent assemblies to Bin/Release folders. Can I give permission to the host agent in VSTS? Is that enough info? Is sharing Build Log report (in private)  helpful?

Comment: I'd like to double confirm with you do you use hosted agent or local agent? I couldn't reproduce your issue with hosted agent, but could reproduce it with local agent. What's the usage of identity TASKAGENT5-0010\buildguest?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT The value in the Queue dropdown is Hosted. Below you can see the log section where the build breaks.

Comment: @Cece-MSFT
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /Website -p Website\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\Website 
##[error]ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error ASPRUNTIME: The current identity (TASKAGENT5-0003\buildguest) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.
 SPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: The current identity (TASKAGENT5-0003\buildguest) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'. [C:\a\1\s\Website.metaproj]
Done Building Project C:\a\1\s\Website.metaproj

Comment: @Mori, Sorry, I still couldn't reproduce your issue with the Hosted agent. We can't modify anything on the hosted server. You may configure a local agent to run the build.

Comment: Are you publishing the web app during the build?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT No I just build it.